# Второй клик на тот же элемент

Tags: jquery

Есть, к примеру, простой параграф с текстом, как я могу менять цвет текста нажимая на него мышкой?

Пытался как то через `.click` сделать но не могу вернуть цвет назад после того как один раз уже нажал на элемент. Раньше за такой функционал отвечал метод `.toggle`, но не могу найти информацию о том как теперь решается подобный вопрос через jQuery.

П.С. Логика как в коде ниже

```js
$('#something').click(
    function() {
        // First click
    },
    function() {
        // Second click
    }
);
```

Comment: Клика будет всего два?

Comment: @Cheg Интересуют 2 варианта, вариант если 2 клика, и вариант если больше 2х... буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определить был ли клик на элементе можно проверкой на наличие класса, который вы будет добавлять при первом клике и убирать при втором:

```js
$('#something').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { // если класса нет
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // добавляем класс
    console.log('First click'); // код для первого клика
  } else { // если есть
    $(this).removeClass('clicked'); // убираем класс
    console.log('Second click'); // код для второго клика
  }
});
```

```css
.text.clicked {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за оперативность, только один вопрос, чем лучше использовать .on вместо .click?

Comment: @lNaydI, использует меньше памяти, дает возможность отключать слушатель через `$elem.off('click', func)`, позволяет обращаться к дочерним элементам, а не только к самому объекту (полезно для динамических дочерних элементов)

Answer (score 4):

Можно заносить кол-во кликов в переменную и проверять кратность/некратность 2ум (`numOfClicks % 2 !== 0`):

```js
let numOfClicks = 0;
const $elem = $('#something');

$elem.on('click', () => {
  ++numOfClicks;
  if(numOfClicks % 2 !== 0) console.log('Odd Click!');
  else console.log('Even Click!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="something">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Для вашей задачи:

```js
let numOfClicks = 0;
const $elem = $('#something');

$elem.on('click', () => {
  ++numOfClicks;
  $elem.toggleClass('odd-click', numOfClicks % 2 !== 0);
});
```

```css
#something.odd-click { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="something">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: Интересное решение, никогда не думал в этом направлении при решении таких задач. (+) от меня

Comment: @Cheg, ;) [6 символов нужно...]

Comment: Но, насколько могу судить, вариант с классом несколько производительнее?

Comment: @Cheg, не думаю, по идее быстрее оперировать переменной в области видимости, чем парсить строку с классами.